# Sync Database between client (android) and server (rails PostgreSQL)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, synchronization

We are building a call management software that allows different people to get calls assigned to them which they can edit on the mobile and then close the call from the mobile which gets synced back to the server for the central admin to monitor. For a linear flow of data i.e call created on server > sent to mobile > updated on mobile > sent back to server we have been able to establish the flow of data and everything is ok.

I am stuck at the next level of complexity that can arise in this workflow which is if after the call is created and sent to the mobile, if it gets updated on the server then  how to sync this change with the mobile, keeping in mind that there might have been some changes made on the mobile also which have not yet been synced as the call has not been closed. Right now there is no automated sync in place and the mobile user has to press a button that indicates an action for sending data back to the server when the call is closed which is what we would like to have as part of the workflow. At the same time we would like some automation to happen with regards to data sync and update till the call is closed.

The analogy I can draw out is with git and code versioning (pull before you push) but there merge conflicts can occur which have to be manually solved.

Appreciate any insights into this issue.

ps: Implementation on SQLite in android and PostgreSQL (ruby on rails) with the mobile aping the data structure from the server storing respective ids of the records from the server to call REST APIs for updating the data back on the server.

Answer (score 0):

So we managed to write a lot of custom APIs to handle all the data exchange between the server and the clients. We came up with a custom conflict resolution that described a higher priority to all the data fields editable from the mobile so every time data is synced to the mobile the higher priority data is saved (i.e. if the mobile has changed those fields then those values are kept even if the server also has changed the data). 
Also we do a data pull from server before editing the data in the mobile to ensure that always the latest data is available.
This falls in line with the business logic we are trying to implement hence cannot generalize this.